# Arrays and Indexing VB.NET programming

Tags: c#, arrays, vb.net, indexing, structure

I am very new to VB and have no clue how to get things to work properly.

What I was trying to do is to create a `Structure` and then create an array of the structure(Must be a single array).

I think I created the structure in the right way but after creating an array of that structure. I tried assigning values to to it. I get this error:

> Error 1   Structure
>
> 'CashRegisterApp.Form1.itemStructure' cannot be indexed because it has no default property.   C:\Users\User\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\CashRegisterApp\CashRegisterApp\Form1.vb    28  9   CashRegisterApp

I am trying to accomplish this:

- create a single array that can be accessed from anywhere in the class(static class variable). i should be able to store cost of items.
- then create an integer value called index in same location that will store current index in array(last used location)
- then add cost to current location and increase index by 1
  `

This is what I done so far and now I'm stuck.

```
    Public Class Form1
    Dim itname As String
    Dim itCost As Integer

    <VBFixedArray(9)> Dim itemArray As itemStructure

    Sub calculateTotal()

    End Sub

    Public Structure itemStructure
        Public itnm As String
        Public itcst As Integer

    End Structure



    Private Sub Label2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label2.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        End
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        itemArray(0) = {"Sweet", 2} // error come in here

        'check to see if the text boxes are empty

        'Query through form and find Type TextBox which in this case we have 2 which are itemName and ItemCost.'
        Dim emptyTextBoxes =
        From txt In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
        Where (txt.Text.Length = 0)
        Select txt.Name
        If emptyTextBoxes.Any Then
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Please fill following textboxes: {0}",
                            String.Join(",", emptyTextBoxes))) 'if tesxtboxes found are empty or null etc. return a message with textbox names
        Else

            Try
                itname = itemName.Text
                itCost = Integer.Parse(itemCost.Text)
                ListBox1.Items.Add(itname)
                ListBox1.Items.Add(itCost)
            Catch Exc As System.OverflowException 'catch system overflow exception. this handles int walues greater than that of int32 
            End Try
            End If


    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        itemName.Clear()
        itemCost.Clear()

    End Sub
End Class
```

If I can just get a pointer in the right direction I would be grateful.

Comment: If you want to create something global you could create a class in a module and initialize a List(Of yourclass) in that module and just call that. However you should remember that this won't keep data if the app is closed. If you want to always keep the data the best solution would be a local database file.

Comment: This line doesn't do what you think it does:  `<VBFixedArray(9)> Dim itemArray As itemStructure`.  Try this instead:  `Dim itemArray(8) As itemStructure`  Note that in VB, when declaring an array, the number used is the _upper bound_ and not the size.  So this declaration creates an array with 9 items.

Comment: Thanks for that. I Managed to complete the exercise already. just needed to educate myself on vb. It all good now. Thanks for clearing that for me. means alot